# End of buffer in COMMIT_EDITMSG buffer when i space

Tags: buffers

I keep hitting a strange issue with the COMMIT_EDITMSG buffer on some occasions I can not insert a space, I can type all other alpha numeric characters just not insert a space between words.

When i hit space `End of buffer` is displayed in the mini buffer, I have a hunch another plugin is modifying this key because its used by a modal plugin in other modes, anyone encountered anything similar or how can I debug because there is technically no errors.

Comment: Start with `<f1> k SPC` which should tell you what `SPC` is bound to.

Comment: I will try that when it next happens and report back :)

Comment: Seems space is getting bound to `(scroll-up-command &optional ARG)` not sure whats triggering this how ever :/

Comment: seems to always be in org buffers that I hit this issues, but not for ever org buffer.

Comment: If you run Emacs 27, it will also tell you which map the key is bound in. For earlier Emacs, you could copy in [`help--binding-locus`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/help.el#n698) and evaluate `(help--binding-locus " " nil)`.

Comment: If I run `help--binding-locus` it returns org-mode-map so I guess that means org-mode-map is binding spc to `scroll-up-command` for some reason

Comment: Oh, I wonder why org-mode is coming into this. Have you set `git-commit-major-mode` to `org-mode`?

Comment: Yeah I did, seems I get a similar issue in any org buffer just inconsistently so feels like something else is triggering it still not worked out what.

Comment: Maybe you could catch it with `(defun check-define-key (fun keymap key def)
  (when (and (eq keymap org-mode-map)
             (eq def 'scroll-up-command))
    (debug nil "binding scroll-up-command in org-mode"))
  (apply fun keymap key def))
(advice-add 'define-key :around #'check-define-key)`

Comment: Removing `magit` because this is not really a Magit issue. It should be possible to use `org-mode` as the `git-commit-major-mode`. Since the issue also occurs in other Org buffers, this is either an Org issue or an issue with the user customization (of Org).